# Cut entire row where specific cell contains a keyword and paste it into a new worksheet while shifting remaining cells up to fill in the blank spaces

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to copy/paste rows from one worksheet to another if the B column contains 'Complete'. There is a drop down list in the column so I do not know if that is affecting anything but it is not copying/pasting all rows into the new worksheet. When I run it, only 4 of the 7 total rows that contain 'Complete' transfer over. This is the code I am using:

```
Sub TransferComplete()
    Dim o As Range
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("In Progress")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Complete")

    p = 3     ' To Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
    For Each o In Source.Range("B3:B1000")   
        If o = "Complete" Then
           Source.Rows(o.Row).Copy Target.Rows(p)
           Source.Rows(o.Row).EntireRow.Delete
           p = p + 1
        End If
    Next o
End Sub
```

I just want it to automatically transfer rows to the new worksheet when 'Complete' is selected from the drop down list. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Side notes: use `Long` instead of `Integer`. And if you're going to delete, you need to loop from the bottom up.

Comment: You could also accomplish this with a filter.

Comment: If you are looking for this to happen automatically, take a look at the [Worksheet.Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. Would the filter work more efficiently?

Comment: Possibly, depending on how much data you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looping and deleting, you need to loop from the bottom up.

```
 Dim i as Long
 For i = 1000 to 3 Step -1
      If Source.Cells(i, "B").Value = "Complete" Then
           Source.Rows(i).Copy Target.Rows(p)
           Source.Rows(i).Delete
           p = p + 1
      End If
 Next
```

Side note: use `Long` instead of `Integer`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long) for a detailed discussion why.